# Possible causes of a crc error in Linux?

Tags: linux

When I boot my Arch Linux computer, it loads up Linux, and then comes up with "crc error", and the system halts.

I have replaced the hard-drive, loaded with a clone of the old hard-drive, but I still get the error.

Could faulty memory, a problem with Linux itself, or some other factor be causing this?

Answer (score 4):

Please download and run Memtest86+ to rule out memory errors. If there are any, replace your RAM. If there aren't, get a LiveCD containing smartmontools package from here, boot from it and check your disks' SMART status (as well as run self-tests to detect bad sectors). If everything passes, the issue is elsewhere - however, it's likely that one of the above tests will fail.

Comment: memtest86 is an excellent tool for this- make sure you let it run overnight to really test everything.

Answer (score 1):

Similar issue discussed here, also this could be due a CRC checksum failure that is detected at the time the kernel is decompressed.  If the new hard drive has a copy of the corrupted file, it makes sense that you would see the same result.

Could you post more of the text around the error message?

Answer (score 0):

faulty memory sounds like a very good candidate indeed. Try switching some ram sticks or removing 1 of 2 ( if you have 2 ) to see if it gets any better.

Also try to check your BIOS settings, you may have some stuff there that may be causing it.

I would recommend to install windows on the second drive and try running it to rule out that it's not a linux prob.

Oh, and if you happened to overclock your machine lately make sure you revert the changes.

Comment: thanks, wanted to check if it could be a memory issue, before going to order some

thanks again